# Экспорт массива в CSV документ в Symfony

Tags: php, массивы, symfony, csv, export

Eсть такой массив (через print_r вывел):

```
Array
(
    [id] => 829
    [name] => name surname
    [info] => Array
        (
            [direct] => 13
            [count] => 492
            [total] => 108
            [asoc] => 4.514
        )

    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 530
                    [name] => name surname2
                    [info] => Array
                        (
                            [direct] => 6
                            [count] => 49
                            [asoc] => 3.267
                            [total] => 14
                        )

                    [_children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 628
                                    [name] => name surname3
                                    [info] => Array
                                        (
                                            [direct] => 1
                                            [count] => 1
                                            [asoc] => 1
                                            [total] => 0
                                        )

                                    [_children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 2
                                                    [name] => Name..
                                                    [info] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [direct] => 0
                                                            [count] => 0
                                                            [asoc] => 0
                                                        )

                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )
```

Нужно его записать в CSV файл,сохраняя структуру (дерево). Суть в том, что я перепробовал много методов как записать это в файл, но почему-то у меня ничего не получилось (не судите строго, я в этом деле новичек). CSV документ должен иметь такую структуру:

```
name surname (13, 492, 108,4.514)//в скобках это info из массива                
    name surname2 (6, 49,3.267, 14) 
    name surname3 (1, 1, 1)         
                  name surname4
```

Буду благодарен любой полезной информации (или книгам) по этому вопросу! Спасибо!
Я перебираю рекуривно массив, используя этот метод:

```
public function recursive($array, $file)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
            if (is_array($item) && $key === 'info')
                fputcsv($file, $item);
            elseif (is_array($item)) {
                $this->recursive($item, $file);
            }
            elseif ($key == 'id')
                    continue;
                else
                    fputcsv($file, array($item));
        }
    }
Но увы, это не совсем то, что нужно, структуры нет, всё просто в ряд...
```

Comment: Посмотрите функции `fputcsv`, `fgetcsv` - должны помочь.

Comment: @And, я уже смотрел и пробовал их использовать, если я хочу записать туда что-то свое типа: `fputcsv($file, array('RECORD'));`, то работает хорошо и записывает, но если я туда массив запихиваю или через foreach, то выдает ошибку типа: ожидается массив, получен int. Гуглил, но безуспешно. Может как-то нужно разложить этот массив перед записью?

Comment: Ну так ошибка в том, что вы передаете `int` - разве не логично? Добавьте код в свой вопрос (только не нужно в комменты писать). Что вы уже сделали, пытались сделать.

Comment: @And, дополнил вопрос

Comment: Тогда сделайте какую надо структуру и записывайте через `fputs`. Обычно это через `,` или `;`, где `\n` - новая строка. Значения, содержащие зарезервированные символы (двойная кавычка, запятая, точка с запятой, новая строка) обрамляются двойными кавычками `"`. Если в значении встречаются кавычки — они представляются в файле в виде двух кавычек подряд.